# What does the "removed" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Boston College, two weeks ***removed*** from upsetting USC, took a home loss to Colorado State, 24-21.
>
> Host Pittsburgh, two weeks ***removed*** from an impressive 3-0 start, stumbled for a second straight game, taking a 21-10 defeat to Akron.

I'm not a native English speaker and sort of confused to understand this sentence especially the two "removed"s.

Comment: Then I think it means "ago". two weeks removed = two weeks ago...

Comment: removed from = after

Comment: It's not exactly "standard" English, but American sports commentators often use non-standard syntax and semantics, so it's probably not an unusual usage in context. Learners should be careful to avoid getting this usage confused with the (standard English) *two weeks **away** from [doing something]*, which always means ***before***, not ***after***.

Comment: @MykolasMasaitis Actually, Boston College defeated the **University of Southern California** on September 13th.  See https://www.google.com/#q=bc%20usc%20football.  The South Carolina Gamecocks were playing the University of Georgia on that date.  Both universities are known as "USC" but, in my experience at least, the California school is the one most often denoted.

Comment: '... [just] two weeks on from ...' is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition could be tricky for a non-native speaker. In this particular case *removed* would be a synonym to *after*. Consider a definition from [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/removed):

> separate or remote in space, time, or character

Answer (score 0):

I found the same expression in a speech by the Autralian Prime Minister:
"The Australians were called upon, just three years removed from the landing on Gallipoli."

I assumed it meant "after" otherwise it would make no sense. But thanks for the confirmation ;)